# Why does ActiveRecord fail to create with error "x must exist" but the query "x.exists?" returns true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I must be missing something really obvious, but here goes:

I'm trying to create an Observation, which is something that references several other objects: a student, a task, a user, and a standard.

But, when I run `Observation.create!(...attributes)` I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:         ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Task must exist, User must exist, Standard must exist, Student must exist
```

Yet, before the line `Observation.create!` for each object I did a print, like so:

```
user = User.find(params[:user])
print "User exists? #{User.exists?(params[:user])}"
```

which printed 
`User exists? true`

If all the (Task, User, Standard, Student) records exist, what could cause the Observation to fail with that error?

This is the migration for Observation:

```
class CreateObservations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :observations do |t|
      t.references :task, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :standard, foreign_key: true
      t.references :student, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and this is the model:

```
class Observation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Task
  belongs_to :User
  belongs_to :Standard
  belongs_to :Student
end
```

Comment: What's the current value of `...attributes`?

Comment: `...attributes` was actually: `(student_id: student.id, user_id: user.id, task_id: task.id, standard_id: standard.id)`

Comment: Are those objects already in the database (persisted)? Also, just as a convention maybe, try downcasing your belongs_to arguments (`belongs_to :task`, ...)

Comment: The upcase was done by the rails generator... and it's bitten me in the butt before. . Looks like that was the problem :-). thanks!  As for the other questions, as far as I know those items are persisted as evidenced by print "User exists? #{User.exists?(params[:user])}" where params user was the id of the user I am checking.  I did this for each of the items in the observation...  Evidently, the capitalized references threw off the existence check ... it was probably checking in the Tasks table instead of the tasks table :-|

Comment: I've tried on a fresh rails 5.2.3 app, and using the `belongs_to` argument in downcase made it work.

Comment: Yes that was the answer.  If you post it as an answer I'll mark it so others can see there's an answer to the issue they might be having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs on the `belongs_to` method:

```
def belongs_to(name, scope = nil, **options)
  reflection = Builder::BelongsTo.build(self, name, scope, options)
  Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection
end
```

Then using `:Task` is going to add a different reflection in your project than using `:task`, as they're different objects.

Just update the `belongs_to` arguments in your model with their downcase version.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like:

All belongs to argument will be in lower case

```
class Observation < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :task
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :standard
      belongs_to :student
    end
```